# Converting rgb images to grayscale and renaming them using matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, rgb, grayscale

I have 500 images named Image1.tif all the way to Image500.tif and I need to convert all of them to grayscale and save them as Image1A.tif to Image500A.tif. Is there a quick way to do this? Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have Image Processing Toolbox you can use RGB2GRAY function.

```
for k=1:500
    Ic=imread(['Image' num2str(k) '.tif']);
    Ig=rgb2gray(Ic);
    imwrite(Ig,['Image' num2str(k) 'A.tif'],'tif')
end
```

If you don't there is a solution [here](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-1ASCU/?solution=1-1ASCU).
Substitute rgb2gray line with:

```
Ig = 0.2989 * Ic(:,:,1) + 0.5870 * Ic(:,:,2) + 0.1140 * Ic(:,:,3);
```