# How to convert the RGB image to the gray scale image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision

In Matlab, how do I convert an image which is in the red green and blue (RGB) format to a gray   scale image without using the toolbox.

Comment: Take an average of the channels? `mean(I,3)`

Answer (score 7):

With "the" toolbox: [rgb2gray](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/rgb2gray.html).

Without "the" toolbox: look [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/99136), or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063965/how-can-i-convert-an-rgb-image-to-grayscale-but-keep-one-color) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348037/converting-rgb-images-to-grayscale-and-renaming-them-using-matlab) or [this paper](http://core.kmi.open.ac.uk/download/pdf/823688.pdf) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/687261/converting-rgb-to-grayscale-intensity) or [here](http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2009/08/24/algorithms-convert-color-grayscale/) or ...

That's just the first couple of Google hits for "convert RGB to grayscale" and "convert RGB to grayscale MATLAB".

Summary:

```
gray = 0.2989*img(:,:,1) + 0.5870*img(:,:,2) + 0.1140*img(:,:,3);
```

where `img` is your RGB image.

Comment: @RobertP.: ...trying to make a point subtly :)

Comment: +1 for the luma calculation